# MySQL get all parents with children

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables with one to many relationship. I need query which will return me parent with all children. I can do this in PHP with foreach parent give me all children. Something like this:

Query for all parents:

```
SELECT * FROM parents WHERE deleted=0;
```

Than in PHP in foreach

```
SELECT * FROM children WHERE deleted=0 AND parent_id = {$parentID};
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with one DB query. If somebody can pint me to some tutorial or some simple example :)

Comment: you can do. SELECT table1.name, table2.name FROM table1 AND table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```html
<?php
  /**
    a sample model
  **/
  class Model {
  
    public function getParentsWithChildren() {

      $out = array();
  
      //you have your PDO instance...
      $query = $pdostmt->query('SELECT * FROM parents WHERE (deleted = 0)');
  
      while ($data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        
        $out[] = array(
          $data->id, $data->column_name, $this->getChildren($data->id)
        );
        
      }
    
      $query->closeCursor();
    
      return $out;

    }

    public function getChildren($parent) {
        
      $out = array();

      $query = $pdostmt->prepare('SELECT * FROM children WHERE (deleted = 0) AND (parent_id = ?)');
      $query->execute(array($parent));

      while ($data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        
        $out[] = array(
          $data->id, $data->column_name, $data->other_column
        );
        
      }
    
      $query->closeCursor();
    
      return $out;
        
    }
    
  }
?>
```

There you can use it like :

```html
<?php
  //your php file

  include('path/to/the/Model.php');

  $model = new Model;

  $parentComplete = $model->getParentsWithChildren();

?>
```

You could get an array with this structure :

```
(
  0 => (
         0 => 1,
         1 => example_parent,
         2 => (
                0 => (
                       0 => 1,
                       1 => example_child_1
                     ),
                1 => (
                       0 => 1,
                       1 => example_child_2
                     )
              )
       ),
   1 => (
    //...
   )
)
```